# Filter in mat-table does not work when I load data about a service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I call up the data via a service and get it to my mat-table. I would like to filter them. Unfortunately my code does not work. Where is the error? Can you please help me?

My Code:

```
 <div class="filter-header">
   <mat-form-field class="filter-input">
     <label>
       <input matInput #filter (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Durchsuchen" />
      </label>
      <button mat-icon-button matSuffix aria-label="clear" *ngIf="filter.value" (click)="filter.value=''; applyFilter('');">x
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

```
export class TableBasicExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'userId', 'title', 'completed'];
  
  public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Data> = null;

  // Overview of the ViewChilds
  @ViewChild('filter', {static: true}) filter: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('tableWrapper', {static: true}) tableWrapper: ElementRef;

  constructor(private service : APIServiceService){
    this.service.getData().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = data;
    });
  }

  // Filter
  public applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
    console.log(filterValue.lastIndexOf);
  }

  public cancelFilter() {
    this.dataSource.filter = '';
    this.filter.nativeElement.value = '';
  }

}
```

My Work in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-with-api-call-zwects?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create new `MatTableDataSource`.

Updating the following line would do the trick for you

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
```

instead of

```
this.dataSource = data.
```

Updated the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-with-api-call-skayye?file=app/table-basic-example.html)